# htaccess - can't for the life of me match this URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, match

http://www.matthewsvolvosite.com/for...p?f=11&t=17479

Need to match and 301 redirect that. I've tried

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/for\.\.\.p?f=11&t=17479$ /forums/viewtopic.php?t=17479
```

and

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/for(.*)f=11&t=17479 /forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=17479
```

Neither work. I've searched and tried many examples. I'm at a loss.

The .htaccess file does match and redirect many other strings.

```
RewriteBase /
```

is active and working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [mod-rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=11&t=17479$
RewriteRule ^for\.\.\.p$ /forums/viewtopic.php?t=17479 [NC,L,R]
```

The reason why your redirect is not working is because you are using [mod-alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) to handle query strings .

Comment: Brilliant, starkeen. Thank you. (the p=11 in your example needs to be a f=11, but otherwise works like a charm)